# Table columns show & hide based on width calculation is not working in Safari IOS devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, safari

I'm trying to find why this script is failing on certain devices. It's working correctly in Firefox, Chrome and even IE browsers but not Safari IOS.

I'm using an iPad to test results via a JS Fiddle here:
[**Example »**](https://jsfiddle.net/bm6k3ddg/4/)

The HTML is taken from a UAT site so is a little chunky but I have reduced it down slightly. As well as the script which has been stripped down from the original 1000 lines.

**JavaScript for the column calculation:**

```
 $.fn.manageColumns = function () {
    function isVisible () {
        return $(this).css("display") !== "none";
    }
    try {
        var $that = $(this);
        var $parent = $that.closest("form");
        var data = $parent.data("state");
        if (! $.isPlainObject(data)) { data = $parent.attr("data-state"); }
        if (! $.isPlainObject(data)) { throw new TypeError("data-state not an object"); }
        console.log(typeof data);
        if ($.isPlainObject(data)) {
            var groups = data.groups;
            var groupString = "";
            $.each(groups, function (key, value) {
                groupString += "[data-column-group=\"" + value + "\"],";
            });
            if (groupString.length) {
                groupString = groupString.slice(0, -1);
            }
            console.log(groupString);
            var $visible = $that.find(groupString).not(".column-vis");
            var $hidden = $that.find("[data-column-group]").not(".column-vis").not($visible);
            var $all = $that.find("[data-column-all]").not(".column-vis");
            $all.hide();
            $visible.show();
            if ($parent.width() < $that.width()) {
                console.log("Will hide columns to fit screen size");
                var maxIterations = 100;
                var minGroups = 1;
                var group = Number.MAX_VALUE;
                for ( ; ($parent.width() < $that.width()) && (maxIterations > 0) &&
                        (group > minGroups); --maxIterations) {
                    var $nextElem = $that.find("col").filter(isVisible).last();
                    group = parseInt($nextElem.data("column-group"));
                    $that.find("[data-column-group=\"" + group + "\"]").not(".column-vis").hide();
                }
                var span = 0;
                $that.find("col").each(function () {
                    var $vCol = $(this);
                    if ($vCol.isVisible()) {
                        var columnSpan = parseInt($vCol.attr("span"));
                        if (columnSpan <= 0) {
                            columnSpan = 1;
                        }
                        span += parseInt(columnSpan);
                    }
                });
                $all.attr("colspan", span).show();
            }
            else {
                console.log("Don't need to hide columns");
                $all.show();
                $hidden.hide();
                $visible.show();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<body><div class="test-widget test-table-container"><div class="test-widget-bg"></div><span class="test-icon icon-setup test-icon-corner"></span><p class="test-widget-title">Schedule</p><p class="test-widget-info"></p><div><div><div class="test-table-gutter"><div class="test-table"><form action="javascript:;" autocomplete="off" data-feature-id="54188" data-source-id="a586120c-e3df-44a4-ab21-ef59c9a9f111" data-target-id="56836" data-widget-id="748" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"><table class="test-data-table table table-bordered table-hover table-column-control table-active"><colgroup><col class="row-status-color" span="1" /><col class="select-all-rows" span="1" /><col data-column-group="1" span="1" /><col data-column-group="2" span="1" /><col data-column-group="3" span="1" /><col data-column-group="4" span="1" /><col data-column-group="5" span="6" /><col data-column-group="6" span="5" /><col data-column-group="7" span="3" /><col data-column-group="8" span="7" /><col data-column-group="9" span="5" /></colgroup><thead><tr><th colspan="32" data-column-all="all"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9"><div class="test-table-filters test-table-match"><div><div class="test-table-filter" data-filter-id="55f025e2-c68e-4210-a174-e34395a3e5dc"></div></div></div></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"><div class="test-table-control test-table-match"><div class="test-auto-key test-control-select"></div><div class="multiselect test-control-select"><div class="select-box"><ul class="form-control"><li>Columns</li></ul><div class="checkboxes-over-select"></div></div><div class="checkboxes"><label for="2fba68e2-7d23-46bb-b340-075ef549b51f"><input checked="checked" class="column-vis" data-column-group="1" id="2fba68e2-7d23-46bb-b340-075ef549b51f" type="checkbox" />Name</label><label for="85f5631d-4fa2-4708-9001-075d67104ec6"><input checked="checked" class="column-vis" data-column-group="2" id="85f5631d-4fa2-4708-9001-075d67104ec6" type="checkbox" />Zone</label><label for="0a1e4226-4402-47ec-ae98-426ee767a4ed"><input checked="checked" class="column-vis" data-column-group="3" id="0a1e4226-4402-47ec-ae98-426ee767a4ed" type="checkbox" />Status</label><label for="47ebdbde-3f49-4d40-a855-d27b82865c50"><input checked="checked" class="column-vis" data-column-group="4" id="47ebdbde-3f49-4d40-a855-d27b82865c50" type="checkbox" />Roamable</label><label for="f70ceb61-1b6f-41cd-b251-5735dc7bd6b6"><input checked="checked" class="column-vis" data-column-group="5" id="f70ceb61-1b6f-41cd-b251-5735dc7bd6b6" type="checkbox" />Schedule</label><label for="2ef942c6-af71-4c00-ac95-0d87d443b8fd"><input checked="checked" class="column-vis" data-column-group="6" id="2ef942c6-af71-4c00-ac95-0d87d443b8fd" type="checkbox" />Authentication</label><label for="8ff2a2c5-5c1f-4ff7-bb99-95adfa20fe04"><input checked="checked" class="column-vis" data-column-group="7" id="8ff2a2c5-5c1f-4ff7-bb99-95adfa20fe04" type="checkbox" />Device</label><label for="babda357-ae2e-41fe-8434-4bf43a969c6d"><input checked="checked" class="column-vis" data-column-group="8" id="babda357-ae2e-41fe-8434-4bf43a969c6d" type="checkbox" />Vanity</label><label for="ca231149-ec2b-4235-b797-5616461190d7"><input checked="checked" class="column-vis" data-column-group="9" id="ca231149-ec2b-4235-b797-5616461190d7" type="checkbox" />Traffic</label></div></div><div class="test-row-count test-control-select"></div></div></div><div class="col-xs-12 test-attached-filters"></div></th></tr><tr class="column-grouping"><th class="row-status-color"></th><th></th><th colspan="1" data-column-group="1"></th><th colspan="1" data-column-group="2"></th><th colspan="1" data-column-group="3"></th><th colspan="1" data-column-group="4"></th><th colspan="6" data-column-group="5" style="background:rgb(109, 56, 107); color:#FFF;">Schedule</th><th colspan="5" data-column-group="6" style="background:rgb(204, 155, 56); color:#FFF;">Authentication</th><th colspan="3" data-column-group="7" style="background:rgb(192, 105, 119); color:#FFF;">Device</th><th colspan="7" data-column-group="8" style="background:rgb(150, 150, 116); color:#FFF;">Vanity</th><th class="last" colspan="5" data-column-group="9" style="background:rgb(138, 126, 149); color:#FFF;">Traffic</th></tr><tr class="column-headers"><th class="row-status-color"></th><th class="select-all-rows"><input class="check-all-rows" type="checkbox" /></th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="1" data-source-id="49421">Name</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="2" data-source-id="56844">Zone</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="3" data-source-id="49426">Status</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="4" data-source-id="49427">Roamable</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="5" data-source-id="56841">Recurrence</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="5" data-source-id="56842">Limit</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="5" data-direction="ascending" data-source-id="49424">From</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="5" data-source-id="49425">Until</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="5" data-source-id="56852">Preparation Period</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="5" data-source-id="56853">Cleanup Period</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="6" data-source-id="56855">Default Access Code</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="6" data-source-id="56856">Bandwidth</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="6" data-source-id="56857">Priority Access Code</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="6" data-source-id="56858">Bandwidth</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="6" data-source-id="49431">Alert Threshold</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="7" data-source-id="49432">Limit</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="7" data-source-id="49434">Alert Threshold</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="7" data-source-id="49433">Currently Active</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="8" data-source-id="56849">SSID</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="8" data-source-id="56851">SSID Grace Period</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="8" data-source-id="56850">Hide</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="8" data-source-id="56846">Encryption</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="8" data-source-id="56847">Protocol</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="8" data-source-id="56848">Key</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="8" data-source-id="56845">VLAN</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="9" data-source-id="49438">Upload</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="9" data-source-id="49440">Packets</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="9" data-source-id="49439">Download</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="9" data-source-id="49441">Packets</th><th class="column-sortable check-active" data-column-group="9" data-source-id="49437">Logging</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="data-row" data-anch-target="28"><td class="row-status-color" style="background: rgb(109, 56, 107)"></td><td class="selecting"><input class="check" type="checkbox" value="28" /></td><td class="expand bold" data-column-group="1">Test</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="2">Guest</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="3">Active</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="4"><span class="icon-no"></span></td><td class="expand" data-column-group="5">Once</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="5">0</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="5">2016-03-08 00:00:00</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="5">2016-03-09 18:00:00</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="5">01:00:00</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="5">01:00:00</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="6">standard</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="6">Regular Speed Conference</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="6">best</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="6">Complimentary Low Speed (Lobby)</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="6">90</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="7">3</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="7">70</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="7">0</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="8">UAT_Test_SSID</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="8">00:30:00</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="8"><span class="icon-no"></span></td><td class="expand" data-column-group="8">None</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="8">WPA_CCMP</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="8"></td><td class="expand" data-column-group="8">UAT_CONFERENCE</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="9">0</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="9">0</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="9">0</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="9">0</td><td class="expand" data-column-group="9"><span class="icon-no"></span></td></tr></tbody></table></form></div></div></div></div></div></body>
```

If you expand the window on the JS Fiddle example you will see the columns hiding and displaying based on the screen width.

I know it's a little rough around the edges but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your problem seems to be with Safari in general, i will take a look later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootstrap is assigning 100% as table width and table max-width so in Safari your `if ($parent.width() < $that.width())` does not work because `that` being the table is as large as the window and not more.

Just add

```
.table {
    width: intrinsic;
    max-width:intrinsic;
}
```

to your css and you are done

Comment: That has fixed the issue. I have been battling with this for a little while now, thank you so much for your help!